# How to install ubuntu alongside windows?

Tags: windows

I already have Windows 8.1 on my ultrabook, how do i install ubuntu alongside it? i do not have a spare usb drive nor does my laptop have an optical drive.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility to do it would be to use virtual machines, for instance, by using virtualbox. Virtualbox can be used to create a "new machine" within your existing system into which you can install.

Virtualbox is able to mount iso files so that even without a physical optical drive installer CDs can be made to appear as virtual optical drives on a client virtual machine.